# How come LibreOffice is lacking a desktop publishing program?

Tags: desktop-computer, libreoffice

I've looked through all the applications now and none of them seem suitable for creating an e-zine or newspaper or magazine or something. Maybe Writer comes the closest, but it would be a very limited such. I don't think it supports columns, even, but I might be wrong.

I know of Scribus, which I find very difficult to use. Is desktop publishing already a "dead art" which no longer deserves anything but a half-broken, obscure, separate FOSS project?

Answer (score 0):

This is a recurring question on ask.libreoffice.org, most recently last week:

https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/242844/does-libreoffice-have-an-equivalent-to-publisher-please/

FOSS choices available are Scribus, LibreOffice Draw (which opens publisher files), Writer, or Impress.

Writer does support columns: *Format -> Columns*.

Commercial software includes MS Publisher, Adobe InDesign, and QuarkXPress.

After writing this answer, I realized that it may be more appropriate for [software recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).